# How to disable inline edit for specific profiles

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How to disable inline Edit for certain profiles.

```
      <lightning:datatable 
                         keyField="Id" 
                         aura:id="subscriberTable" 
                         data="{! v.data }" 
                         columns="{! v.columns }" 
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true" 
                         showRowNumberColumn="false" 
                         initialRows="{! v.recordsToDisplay}" sortedBy="{! v.sortedBy }" 
                         sortedDirection="{! v.sortedDirection }" 
                         onsort="{! c.updateColumnSorting}" 
                         draftValues="{! v.draftValues }" 
                         onsave="{! c.handleSaveEdition }" />
</div>
```

Js side:

```
     component.set('v.columns', [{
            label: 'Name',
            fieldName: 'Name',
            type: 'text',
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Alias',
            fieldName: 'Alias__c',
            type: 'text',
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Point of Contact(Email)',
            fieldName: 'Email__c',
            type: 'text',
            sortable: true,
            editable: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Active',
            fieldName: 'Active__c',
            type: 'boolean',
            sortable: true,
            editable: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Portal Access',
            fieldName: 'Portal_Access__c',
            type: 'boolean',
            sortable: true,
            editable: true,

        },


    ]);
```

**How to set "Active" field editable to false for these  2 profiles (Test1,Test2)**.In normal Table we can use aura:if but Iam not sure how to do this here.

**//I have tried this approach but it works but a lot of code**

JS side:

```
  helper.userEditAccess(component,event,helper);
```

Helper:

```
   userEditAccess: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.canUserEdit");
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var state = a.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
            if (a.getReturnValue() == true) {
                component.set('v.columns', [{
                        label: 'Name',
                        fieldName: 'Name',
                        type: 'text',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Alias',
                        fieldName: 'Alias__c',
                        type: 'text',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Point of Contact(Email)',
                        fieldName: 'Email__c',
                        type: 'text',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Active',
                        fieldName: 'Active__c',
                        type: 'boolean',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: false
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Portal Access',
                        fieldName: 'Portal_Access__c',
                        type: 'boolean',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: false,

                    },


                ]);
            } else if (a.getReturnValue() == false) {
                component.set('v.columns', [{
                        label: 'Name',
                        fieldName: 'Name',
                        type: 'text',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Alias',
                        fieldName: 'Alias__c',
                        type: 'text',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Point of Contact(Email)',
                        fieldName: 'Email__c',
                        type: 'text',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Active',
                        fieldName: 'Active__c',
                        type: 'boolean',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Portal Access',
                        fieldName: 'Portal_Access__c',
                        type: 'boolean',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: true,

                    },


                ]);
            }
        } 
    });
    // enqueue the action 
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Apex class:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Boolean canUserEdit() {
    List<string>profileNameList=new List<string>();
    List<user>userList=[SELECT ID,PROFILE.NAME,PROFILE.Id FROM USER where profile.name='Test-Admin'];
    for(User us:userList){
        profileNameList.add(us.PROFILE.Id);
    }
    Id profileId = UserInfo.getProfileId();
    if(profileNameList.contains(profileId)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assign a custom permission to both profiles check whether the user has custom permission or not during init of component based on that set editable "true" or "false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With the usage of Apex

Assuming this is your Controller:

```
public class TestController {

    public  static final Set<Id> EDIT_ALLOWED_PROFILE_IDS = new Set<Id> {
        '00e2o000001XMNaAAO',
        '00e2o000001XMNaBCS'
    };

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Boolean canUserEdit() {
        Id profileId = UserInfo.getProfileId();
        return EDIT_ALLOWED_PROFILE_IDS.contains(profileId);
    }
}
```

`EDIT_ALLOWED_PROFILE_IDS` can be of course initialized via Custom Settings, Custom Metadata and so on.

Then use this method in your JS code and assign its result to the `editable` property.

**LWC version**

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                show-row-number-column
                row-number-offset={rowOffset}
                suppress-bottom-bar
                columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import canUserEdit from '@salesforce/apex/TestController.canUserEdit';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name'},
    { label: 'Website', fieldName: 'website', type: 'url'},
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone'},
    { label: 'CloseAt', fieldName: 'closeAt', type: 'date'},
    { label: 'Balance', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency'}
];

export default class TestLwcComponent extends LightningElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        canUserEdit()
            .then(result => {
                this.columns.forEach(function (item, index) {
                    item.editable = result
                });
                this.columns = [...this.columns];
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        this.data = [
            {
                "name":"Maddison Emard",
                "email":"Aiyana61@hotmail.com",
                "website":"https://jennings.org",
                "amount":"134.01",
                "phone":"803.854.4656 x4777",
                "closeAt":"2020-04-22T22:31:35.941Z",
                "id":"1baf5e28-f839-4ddd-84ee-e71f0bcca59d"
            },
            {
                "name":"Lilla Stamm",
                "email":"Rebeka95@gmail.com",
                "website":"http://princess.net",
                "amount":"306.11",
                "phone":"1-753-685-9600 x9132",
                "closeAt":"2020-05-29T10:20:59.730Z",
                "id":"4d38f892-0c6e-42c1-beb3-a41faae1c501"
            },
            {
                "name":"Pauline Labadie",
                "email":"Santos_Grady@gmail.com",
                "website":"https://mafalda.name",
                "amount":"57.54",
                "phone":"860.982.3835 x2136",
                "closeAt":"2021-01-08T23:48:57.409Z",
                "id":"ad225ea1-8a64-4a05-99e9-bba42c865d45"
            }
        ];
    }

    @track columns = columns;
    @track data = [];
    @track rowOffset = 0;
}
```

**Aura version**

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="TestController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="errors" type="Object" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="draftValues" type="Object" default="[]"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>

    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <h1 class="slds-text-heading_large">Inline edit playground</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 300px">
        <lightning:datatable
            columns="{! v.columns }"
            data="{! v.data }"
            keyField="id"
            errors="{! v.errors }"
            draftValues="{! v.draftValues }"
        />
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.canUserEdit");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var canEdit = response.getReturnValue();
                cmp.set('v.columns', [
                    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name', editable: canEdit},
                    { label: 'Website', fieldName: 'website', type: 'url', editable: canEdit},
                    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone', editable: canEdit},
                    { label: 'CloseAt', fieldName: 'closeAt', type: 'date', editable: canEdit},
                    { label: 'Balance', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency', editable: canEdit}
                ]);
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

        cmp.set('v.data', [
            {
                "name":"Maddison Emard",
                "email":"Aiyana61@hotmail.com",
                "website":"https://jennings.org",
                "amount":"134.01",
                "phone":"803.854.4656 x4777",
                "closeAt":"2020-04-22T22:31:35.941Z",
                "id":"1baf5e28-f839-4ddd-84ee-e71f0bcca59d"
            },
            {
                "name":"Lilla Stamm",
                "email":"Rebeka95@gmail.com",
                "website":"http://princess.net",
                "amount":"306.11",
                "phone":"1-753-685-9600 x9132",
                "closeAt":"2020-05-29T10:20:59.730Z",
                "id":"4d38f892-0c6e-42c1-beb3-a41faae1c501"
            },
            {
                "name":"Pauline Labadie",
                "email":"Santos_Grady@gmail.com",
                "website":"https://mafalda.name",
                "amount":"57.54",
                "phone":"860.982.3835 x2136",
                "closeAt":"2021-01-08T23:48:57.409Z",
                "id":"ad225ea1-8a64-4a05-99e9-bba42c865d45"
            }
        ]);
    }
});
```

### Without the usage of Apex

**Aura version**

Instead of the Apex controller, you can use a [Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm).

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="TestController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="errors" type="Object" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="draftValues" type="Object" default="[]"/>

    <aura:attribute type="String" name="permittedProfiles" default="{!join('','00e2o0000022wBLAAY,', '00e2o000001XMNaBCS')}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="currentUser" type="User" />
    <force:recordData
        fields="Name, Email, UserType, ProfileId"
        recordId="{!$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id}"
        targetFields="{!v.currentUser}"
        mode="VIEW"
        recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
    />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>

    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <h1 class="slds-text-heading_large">Inline edit playground</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 300px">
        <lightning:datatable
            columns="{! v.columns }"
            data="{! v.data }"
            keyField="id"
            errors="{! v.errors }"
            draftValues="{! v.draftValues }"
        />
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set('v.data', [
            {
                "name":"Maddison Emard",
                "email":"Aiyana61@hotmail.com",
                "website":"https://jennings.org",
                "amount":"134.01",
                "phone":"803.854.4656 x4777",
                "closeAt":"2020-04-22T22:31:35.941Z",
                "id":"1baf5e28-f839-4ddd-84ee-e71f0bcca59d"
            },
            {
                "name":"Lilla Stamm",
                "email":"Rebeka95@gmail.com",
                "website":"http://princess.net",
                "amount":"306.11",
                "phone":"1-753-685-9600 x9132",
                "closeAt":"2020-05-29T10:20:59.730Z",
                "id":"4d38f892-0c6e-42c1-beb3-a41faae1c501"
            },
            {
                "name":"Pauline Labadie",
                "email":"Santos_Grady@gmail.com",
                "website":"https://mafalda.name",
                "amount":"57.54",
                "phone":"860.982.3835 x2136",
                "closeAt":"2021-01-08T23:48:57.409Z",
                "id":"ad225ea1-8a64-4a05-99e9-bba42c865d45"
            }
        ]);
    },
    handleRecordUpdated: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var permittedProfilesAttribute = cmp.get('v.permittedProfiles');
        var permittedProfilesArray = permittedProfilesAttribute.split(',');
        var eventParams = event.getParams();

        if(eventParams.changeType === "LOADED") {
            var currentUser = cmp.get('v.currentUser');
            var canEdit = permittedProfilesArray.includes(currentUser.ProfileId);

            cmp.set('v.columns', [
                { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name', editable: canEdit},
                { label: 'Website', fieldName: 'website', type: 'url', editable: canEdit},
                { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone', editable: canEdit},
                { label: 'CloseAt', fieldName: 'closeAt', type: 'date', editable: canEdit},
                { label: 'Balance', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency', editable: canEdit}
            ]);
        }
    }
});
```

The examples above are based on Datatable Example: Data Table With Inline Edit from [LWC Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) and [Aura Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example).

Comment: Thanks got it. without apex any work arround??

Comment: @AnnappaPH added LWC component utilizing Apex code to my answer. Why not using Apex?

Comment: I will agree with your solution. no comments.but iam looking for anyother work arround?

Comment: @AnnappaPH I believe there is, have a look at [that link](https://rajvakati.com/2019/02/11/get-current-user-details-in-lightning-web-components/). I'll update my answer during the day with another working solution.

Comment: thanks.Its lightning components

Comment: @thanks  Przemysław Tamoń

Comment: @AnnappaPH sorry for the delay - aura w/o apex example added.